# Ember 2.8 Rails 4.2.4: Rails is not receiving payload sent by ember

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ember.js

Simple Rails api back end, ember front end app. I'm trying to create a new record and Ember seems to be formatting the `POST` request correctly:

[image]

It's hitting my controller in the `create` action but there are no `params` getting through. It's simply:

`{"format"=>"json", "controller"=>"api/v1/vehicles", "action"=>"create"}`

`request.headers` does not show any of the vehicle information I'm trying to create.

I've whitelisted everything needed in the controller:

```
def vehicle_params
  params.require(:vehicle).permit(:plate_num, :vehicle_type, :state)
end
```

I have no idea if relevant but I've set up CORS to accept everything:

```
  config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
    allow do
      origins '*'
      resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => :any
    end
  end
```

What else do I need to check?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, created a file `mime_type.rb` in `config/initializers` with the following:

```
api_mime_type = %W(
  application/vnd.api+json
  text/x-json
  application/json
)

Mime::Type.unregister :json
Mime::Type.register 'application/json', :json, api_mime_type
```

This worked for me. Remember to restart the server.